# File with square brackets in name not extracted by tar

Tags: linux, shell, tar

On Linux I'm extracting files from a `tar` archive using

```
tar -xC / -f /tarFile.tar someFolder/[HD] video1.mp4
```

This works always fine but not in this case where file name contains square brackets. Tar response is

```
someFolder/[HD] video1.mp4: not found in archive
```

The file is extracted fine if I remove the square brackets.

I already tried both escaping all characters with `\` and surrounding file name with `'`. No luck.

Any hint? Thanks

Comment: Can you share which `tar --version` and shell you use (`echo $SHELL`)? Can you include the version of commands which you tried with quoting and escaping?

Comment: Is that really the command you typed? It seems like you must have quoted or escaped the space in the filename, otherwise it would see `someFolder/[HD]` and `video1.mp4` as separate arguments.

Answer (score 7):

The first command you have provided will attempt to extract two or three files:

```
someFolder/H
someFolder/D
video1.mp4
```

If you enclose filename in single quotes (`'`) the `tar` program will see the `[HD]` and process it as a glob wildcard meaning "Either `H` or `D`". It will therefore attempt to extract two files:

```
someFolder/H video1.mp4
someFolder/D video1.mp4
```

Quoting the filename *and* using the `--no-wildcards` flag will suppress these attempted expansions:

```
tar -xC / -f /tarFile.tar 'someFolder/[HD] video1.mp4' --no-wildcards
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace square brackets with the wildcard characters (such as `?` or `*`), e.g.

```
tar -x -C/ -v -f tarFile.tar 'someFolder/?HD? video1.mp4'
```

or:

```
tar -x -C. -v -f tarFile.tar 'someFolder/*video1.mp4'
```

To confirm the filename, you can list the archive file by:

```
tar -t -f tarFile.tar | grep mp4$
```

Comment: A tar implementation that implements pattern matching in extract mode is broken.